# Upload file in asp, AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net

where error? if i dont use ajax, then form is valid, and file is uploading, but now page reload and...file not load in path, why?

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <p>

       <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Upload" Text="downdoad..." 
        BackColor="#0099CC" Font-Size="Small" />
    </p>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            downdoad...
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fileupload doesn't work in an updatepanel,
you have a workaround on this url
http://www.codeproject.com/useritems/simpleajaxupload.asp

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads" + FileUpload1.FileName));
            Label1.Text = "Saved Successfully";
        }
        else 
        {
            Label1.Text = "File Not found";
        }
    }
```

In the above code file does not Add in Upload Folder